Programmatically update SQL scripts in my project?
So I built a database script object and changes migrator using DBUp and stored the SQL scripts in the Visual Studio project itself to keep everything versioned.
(folders of .sql files) This is great because I can set my own regex replacer for any linked servers or prod vs UAT changes automatically with preprocessors etc.
However, these can get outdated, while it is perfectly fine to update them manually, some devs would rather there be an update from DB option where it updates the scripts based on the set environment.
It's relatively trivial to retrieve the scripts from the db into my file system, but it doesn't "check in" to git or my Visual Studio project for that matter.
How should I do this?


Why not have linked server names be the same across environments (I assume you name them after actual server names. Try naming them after their purpose)? 2. Investigate synonyms feature.

